# React component that shows the current weather in selected city (temperature, description and weather icon)

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a react component that shows the current weather in the selected city (temperature, description, and weather icon).

I'm using OpenWeatherMap, but I don't know where I should start..

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

```
function Weather() {
    const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState();

    const fetchWeather = () => {
        fetch(
            "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Helsinki &APPID=<APP-ID>"
        )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setWeather(data.results[0].weather);
            });
    };
}
```

Help is needed! Thanks

Comment: can you add code for your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was your fetch request is missing the protocol part at the start of URL(`https://`).

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const cityList = ["Helsinki", "Tampere", "Turku", "Oulu"];

export default function Weather() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState();
  const [city, setCity] = React.useState("Helsinki");

  const fetchWeather = (city) => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&APPID=dc6e198d710d27211ed68a445d1bb01e`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setWeather(data);
      });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchWeather(city);
  }, [city]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <select
          onChange={(e) => {
            setCity(e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          {cityList.map((city) => (
            <option value={city}>{city}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <div>Temparature : {weather?.main?.temp}</div>
        <div>Weather : {weather?.weather?.[0]?.main}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit unruffled-burnell-02vz9]

Comment: @Laura, check this out !!

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working :(

Comment: what's the error you get? I have updated the answer after the initial post. I have changed the APP-ID in the question later. It should be your app id

Comment: It doesn't give any error but also doesn't show anything in the browser

Comment: What has it logged in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing, it's empty :/

Comment: That's weird. Does the code sandbox example works?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I have added a link at the bottom of the answer. It will open a new window to run your code in codesandbox site

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect the city dropdown as well. let me know if you got any issues?

Comment: yeah.. i just don't know how to use it :D

Comment: just click on it, it will be open and run the code and output view side by side